# Using wpdb to search usermeta values

Tags: php, mysql, search, wordpress

I'm trying to create a front-end search user bios in wordpress and return links to profiles as results. So far I haven't had much luck using WP User Query, but I did stumble across the wpdb function.

So far I have a simple mysql query that looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_value` LIKE '%graphic%'
```

But I'm pretty sure I'm screwing that syntax up when I'm using my wpdb function:

```
<?php

$search = 'graphic';

global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
    "
    SELECT * 
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}usermeta 
    WHERE `meta_value` LIKE $search
    ",
));
if(!empty($results)){
    $return = $results;
} else{
    $return = false;    
}
return $return;  ?>
```

My main questions are:
Is there a better way of performing this search?
and
What is the correct syntax for performing a LIKE keyword search using WPDB?

Comment: Please check the link. It will help you. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85092/like-meta-query

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?php

    $search = 'graphic';

    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'META_KEY', 'meta_value' => $search, 'meta_compare' => 'LIKE' ) );

?>
```